# What equation describes black alpha on a white image?

Tags: image-processing

What equation best describes the alpha content of a black colored pixel applied to a white pixel when measuring the resulting pixel intensity?

For instance

- given a white pixel: argb : 255, 255, 255, 255
- drawing over it with a black pixel: argb : 78, 0, 0, 0
- the result is argb : 255, 50.2, 50.2, 50.2

Measuring the pixel's intensity 50.2 should relate an alpha level of 78 when testing for black.

After trying for it, I settled on a rough formula ~>  **A = 1 - (I / 255) ^ 2.193**

Here A = alpha, I = intensity. It could be  **1 - I ^ 2.193**  if the values for I were in the range 0 - 1. This is just a gamma function subtracted from one to orient the values correctly. For white alpha pixels applied to a black image the formula would be  **I ^ 2.193**.
This may not be near the solution but I can't dream it up. I may have heard of this equation using a power of **2.2**, maybe not. Its results are okay, but then again I also liked the results of a linear equation, happily adding 1 level of alpha for each 1 level of intensity less than 255 (white.)

I would really love to read about the science behind this alpha relationship from one of you!

**EDIT ...**
Thanks to Emre my question is answered. And now that I have the solution I have added some figures to turn it into an example...

[image: Image of sphere]
[image: Separated image - white part]
[image: Separated image - alpha part]
**3 images ~> a sphere separated into a white part and an alpha part**

[image: Result obtained using gamma 2.2]
[image: Result obtained using Linear relationship]
**Images obtained using Gamma 2.2 result and Linear result

re-applied to white layers, respectively**

[image: Wikipedia sRGB image]
**Graph from Wikipedia demonstrates the difference between sRGB (standard red green blue) and Gamma 2.2. Here sRGB is the red line plotting the intensity function, and Gamma 2.2 is a black dashed line drawn below the red line. Not much difference**

Thus, **A = 1 - I ^ 2.2**, is nearly correct choice

Comment: You're on the right track. Look up [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) and [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB).

Comment: @Emre 2.2! Thanks for the direction.